# Access refused when browsing directories recursively vb.net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, directory, syntax-error

So basically I just tried to make an recursive directory searcher but I do not know how to "ignore" directories that have admin access only

Code:

```
Dim AppData As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:/Users/" & Environment.UserName & "/Appdata/Roaming", "cache", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Error : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to path' C: \ Users \ User \ Appdata \ Roaming \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Start Menu \ Programs 'is denied.'

Please help

Comment: Use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()`: it won't throw when it enumerates a path that your app / User has no rights to get access to. Unless you're using .Net Core 3.1 / .Net 5, then you have built-in options to skip those paths.

Comment: Or of course `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories()`, if you just need directory entries.

Comment: Use the `IterateFolders` function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794996/how-to-skip-directory-or-file-when-unauthorizedaccessexception) post.